# Constructor which is a part of Object class

Tags: java, constructor

I was reading **[JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7)** about constructors and came across the following:

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor
>   invocation and the constructor being declared ***is not part of the***
>   ***primordial class Object***

The thing is I can't imagine how is constructor being declared can be a part of the class Object? Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All it's trying to say is that the language that follows doesn't apply to the `Object` class (since `Object` has no superclasses).

It does apply to all classes that you and I can declare.

Comment: Indeed, and specifically it is not saying that you can yourself declare additional constructors in class `Object`.